# Nullable Enum property in kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have couple of properties that are  enums and I want to bind them to grid. I am using following code

```
column.ForeignKey(p => p.<EnumpropertyName>, 
Model.<EnumList_As_SelectedItemList>, "Value", "Text");
```

EnumpropertyName is nullable Enum.

In another column, I refer to child property of property

```
column.ForeignKey(p => p.<Enumproperty2Name>.<childProperyName>, 
Model.<AnotherEnumList_As_SelectedItemList>, "Value", "Text");
```

childProperyName is nullable Enum.

As this is inside child object I have

```
.Model(model =>
 {
    model.Id(p => p.InfoTableId);
    model.Field(p => p.<Enumproperty2Name>).DefaultValue(new      Enumproperty2Name());
  })
```

This is not working, as I add new row and select value for these dropdown, value is lost after selection. However if I remove nullable and let them be regular enum properties, they work.

How to make nullable enums work in kendo grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a dropdown inside a Kendo Grid try the following.

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.ExamDateStatus, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ExamStatus"], "Value", "Text")
.Title("Status").EditorTemplateName("ComboForeignKey").Width(100);
```

"ComboForeignKey" is a partial view which resides Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder. It's content must be something similar to following.

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m).OptionLabel("Select Below...")
 .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true"})
 .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with value binding to nullable Enum property. I managed to fix it using chamara's answer.

The most important line there is this one:

```
 .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true"})
```

It forces Kendo editor to bind to primitive value type (thus sending simple number values to your server) instead of

```
System.Nullable<YourEnumType>
```

That value type is later successfully deserialized by the default MVC model binder and converted to your enum value. Unlike the previous option (without the data_value_primitive attribute), in which case the value received is just null.

Comment: Setting data_value_primitive solved my problem too, but I wasn't using an Enum. Looks like Kendo or the binder can trouble with many nullable types. Mine was an int? property.